# SimpleMFRC522 authentication issues with NTAG213 nfc tag

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, nfc, rfid

I have an RFID-RC522 scanner, and NTAG213 NFC tags that I was wanting to read and write data on and off. However any time I try to run write to them, I get the following error

```
AUTH ERROR!!
AUTH ERROR(status2reg & 0x08) !=0
```

I was hoping someone might have some solutions for working around this at all. I am using the SimpleMFRC522 library if that helps. Many thanks!

Comment: Just a quick shot - maybe the page you are trying to write to is write protected ? Please edit your question and provide more data, thanks.